# Ansible Builtin Lineinfile to ~/.bashrc

Tags: ansible

I'm relatively new to ansible, so apologies if this question misses something.

My goal is to add a line to the `~/.bashrc` file with ansible. I think the best way to do that is with the `ansible.builtin.lineinfile` module.

Unfortunately, I've run the module, it appears to run properly on the target host machine, reports back `'changed'` on the first run (and `'ok'` on subsequent runs), but no changes are actually made in the `~/.bashrc` file.

Appreciate any help in figuring out what changes would be needed to create the desired outcome.

```
---

- hosts: setup
  become: true
  vars_files:
    - /etc/ansible/vars.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Test lineinfile
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        path: ~/.bashrc
        line: "test lineinfile"
```

Answer (score 3):

Changed `path: ~/.bashrc` to `path: .bashrc` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple lines could be done this way:

```
    - name: Add an environment variable to the remote user's shell.
      lineinfile:
        dest: "~/.bashrc"
        line: |
            Line 1
            Line 2
```