# Is it good idea to let software installation process automatically edit user's bashrc?

Tags: bash, installation, architecture, software-distribution

The software I use automatically edits my `.bushrc` by adding some lines `export` and `source`. By the way, the software edits bashrc using ansible's like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67594195/ansible-builtin-lineinfile-to-bashrc).

I think this is not a good design choice, because user might sometime unconsciously delete the specific lines in bashrc inserted by the software, and after that user cannot easily get the bashrc back to the original state.

So personally, It would be helpful if installation instruction describes what should be added in the bashrc in the README, rather than let the software edit the bashrc.

I want to hear which (automatically edit or instruction in readme) is better and why?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely on the side of no direct edits to `.bashrc` here. Some people don't even use bash.

The installer should probably generate it's own `~/.somethingrc` file and instructs the user to source it from their .bashrc (or alternative).